# Ошибки разбора CSS

Tags: html, css, uikit

Доброго времени суток.

Решил попробовать UIKit, скачал набор стилей, подключил к HTML-странице, набросал простейшую разметку с grid и panel, открываю страницу - а там куча ошибок "потерянное объявление" и "набор правил проигнорирован из-за плохого селектора".
И страница без оформления.

Вот, если необходимо:

- разметка: gist.github.com/anonymous/8627e1b8b282d846f386
- лог ошибок: gist.github.com/anonymous/c9122be6eb2dbf5e7221
  Браузер - Firefox 33.0.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Не может же CSS UIkit'f в самом деле невалидным? Или может?

**UPD**
Зашёл с другого конца - взял с сайта UIKit простой пример - ошибок разбора CSS нет, но и оформление тоже отсутствует. Ничего не понимаю. :(

Comment: Думаю, все там нормально. Firefox считает ошибками селекторы с префексами других браузеров + вероятно, там предусмотрены какие-то фичи, которые не работают в firefox'е.

...Я так думаю.

Comment: А. Пример из документации не порождает ошибок разбора CSS (хотя CSS-файлы там те же самые).  
Б. Как бы то ни было, оформление стилями не работает ни в моём варианте, ни в официальном.